# CSRF Token mismatch on Ajax Form on change submission

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a public form where it sends Ajax request on jquery onchange event, sometimes due to the number of requests sent in the time interval I'm starting to get TokenMismatchException.

I'm using the following way to send the csrf token:

```
$.ajaxSetup({ 

   headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content') } 

});
```

What would be the solution to my situation? Extending the csrf token lifetime? Thoughts?

Comment: You might want to look at something like that maybe: https://github.com/GeneaLabs/laravel-caffeine

Comment: Are you 100% certain that the `TokenMismatchException` is caused by the number of requests? How did you come to such a conclusion? I've had `TokenMismatchException` because users are using IE. Maybe worth investigating if you have any IE users. https://robinz.in/csrf-token-session-error-with-laravel-on-ie-edge/

Comment: You can exclude the route in VerifyCsrfToken middleware.

Comment: Not sure about this 100% but you can put cache: false, in your ajaxSetup to prevent the token is being cached. Or you can include the _token into your data instead of headers.

Comment: you can assign csrf token globally in a php header. Then you can use it anywhere.

Comment: @haakym I'm facing this problem on Chrome. I think it's not about number of requests - as much as it's about concurrent requests. Also When does Laravel change the session csrf token?

Comment: @AlexMansour Okay. So is this issue caused because `$.ajaxSetup` is not called properly when there are concurrent requests? This would imply your data is going through but the csrf token isn't, right? If so, perhaps consider Can Celik's suggestion: "... include the _token into your data instead of headers."

Answer (score 0):

If the call is not manipulating any sensitive information, put the route in except array in VerifyCsrfToken class.